# Checkbox not checking inside div in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, checkbox

Weird problem.  I don't know if anyone can shed some light on this? I have a checkbox inside a div.  It works fine in IE but not Firefox. I have to click the space around the checkbox that is occupied by the div (sort of like a label) for the checkbox to tick on and off.  Directly clicking the checkbox does not show it as ticked on or off, even though in firebug it is showing that it is in a checked state and an unchecked state.

Only in FF does this happen.....

Comment: If it works in IE, but not a modern browser like Firefox, then obviously the markup is wrong. It sounds like a problem with the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in firebug.  Disabling firebug will stop this behaviour happening.

I had a similar strange thing happening with radio buttons.  Disabling firebug fixed it.